# Minitab 17.2 update - Footnotes appear in all charts

Tags: minitab

Apparently an update was pushed for Minitab 17 and my current version shows 17.2. In this new version, all control charts created with a macro now show footnotes in the trends. The default now shows "Data points used for the calculations: 1-100" and "Results include rows where [conditions used show here]"

My colleague was able to able to get rid of the footnotes by altering the macro code and inserting the following:

`NoOFootnote;
NoSFootnote;
NoXFootnote;
NoPerFootnote.`

Is there a way to change the default settings and remove the footnotes so that I don't have to do this for all my code?

Answer (score 0):

I researched the documentation on Minitab.com and spoke with a representative.  There is currently no option to remove these automated footnotes as a default setting through the Tools>Options settings (which is how you edit other footnote defaults).  I would recommend reaching out to Minitab and letting them know this is a feature you would like to see added to a future version of Minitab.

Also, the subcommand that removes those specific footnotes is the NoOFootnote.